# replace_roles discord.py really confusing?

Tags: python, replace, bots, roles, discord.py

I don't fully understand how to use `replace roles` in **discord.py**. I have searched everywhere on the internet but I still can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

I am trying to make it so the user can **self assign** roles but only have 1 role at a time. For example, if they had the **role "1"** and typed in a command to get **role "2"**, I want the bot to replace **role "1"** with **role "2"** so they should only have **role "2"**.

I made sure the bots role is higher in the hierarchy than the roles I made for people to assign themselves and the bot has manage roles perms. I am not using rewrite and I'm using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass it the `Member` and `Role`s, and it replaces all of the current roles of that member with the roles you passed.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await bot.replace_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
```

You would call this with something like `!giverole @RoleName`. This might result in a `discord.Forbidden` error if the callers highest role is higher than the bots highest role.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py has a helpful function discord.utils.get(), which takes a list of some kind and the parameters you're looking for. For example,

```
targetrole = discord.utils.get(myserver.roles, name="MyTargetRole")
```

Note that if you're changing a user's roles via PM, the server won't be provided to you by the message. You can grab the server the same way from client.servers

Also note that passing message.author to replace_roles via PM will result in error, as that user instance won't have a server. Instead, grab the user from server.members. You can match the name provided from message.author.

Thirdly, note that replace_roles is an asynchronous function. You may want to add 'await' before it, or you might not see any results.